# SwiftUI Picker selection indicators not respecting frame width

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm trying to add 2 Pickers in a HStack with success by using a geometry reader to set the width of the pickers frame. The selection indicators however do not respect the frame it's width. The problem is that the lines in between look different because of the overlap. Does anyone know how to fix this issue or is it not possible since you can't customize the selection indicator as mentioned in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipickerview/1614373-showsselectionindicator)?

```
let range = Range(0...60)
@State index = 0

var body: some View {
   VStack {
      GeometryReader { geometry in
         HStack(spacing: 0) {
            Picker(selection: $index, label: Text("")) {
               ForEach(range) { index in
                  Text("\(index)").tag(index)
               }
            }
            .labelsHidden()
            .frame(width: geometry.size.width / 2)

            Picker(selection: $index, label: Text("")) {
               ForEach(range) { index in
                  Text("\(index)").tag(index)
               }
            }
            .labelsHidden()
            .frame(width: geometry.size.width / 2)
         }
      }
   }
}
```

[image: HStack with 2 pickers]
[image: HStack with 1 picker]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use .clipped for both as in below

```
Picker(selection: self.$index, label: Text("")) {
    ForEach(self.range) { index in
        Text("\(index)").tag(index)
    }
}
.labelsHidden()
.frame(width: geometry.size.width / 2)
.clipped()                                  // << here !!
```