# iOS15 bug? Overlapping touch ares on iPhone screens with some HStack()ed Picker() objects

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

**Hello developers!**

I encountered a situation, where I like to get some **feedback from experienced Swift developers at the pulse of time**.

For an iOS app I need some user inputs, three to be precise. These can be seen as a whole number in the current state. So I thought, to put them in an integer variable. I decided to use Swift as the language and SwiftUI for the Interface.

**Table of contents:**

- Story
- Situation (Problem)
- Question
- Hardware
- Example Code

---

### THE STORY (in short):

I tried to find a way to get the user input into the variable. TextField() handles String. On TextFields()s tap some screen keyboard appears. After input the user can hit the 'return' button and the keyboard disappears. My goal was intercept all characters that did not belong to an integer. So I added a filter function which only allowed numbers from 0 to 9. Fine, but at the default keyboard the user had to hit the symbols button to get a number pad provided.
So I picked a 'Number Pad'. That one has, despite the unpopulated space, no 'return' button. Further the keyboard blocks the view to the Interface. Well, perhaps implementing something like IQKeyboardManager from 'Iftekhar Qurashi' (see: https://cocoapods.org/pods/IQKeyboardManager) can counter the insufficiency, But I asked myself, if such a basic task requires an external library. There should be a native way, right?

---

### THE SITUATION:

After the described and discarded idea, I looked around a went for some Picker()s, which went well... visually. If you grab a picker wheel which has a neighbor to right, you will move the right neighbors wheel. This is shown is a video (just below 'Step 4:'): https://blckbirds.com/post/swiftui-how-to-create-a-multi-component-picker/
Same on the physical devices when in portrait mode(iPhone 6S, X and 13). Landscape offers enough space.

The suggested method to cure the unwanted behavior, namely to add '.compositingGroup().clipped()' to the end of each Picker()s closure does not work for me (iOS 15). As mentioned in the comments by 'Dave Reed', the fact, that the pickers work fine on my Intel MacBooks Xcode (preview and simulators) could be that im running currently 13.1. over there.
For the screenshot I commented the 'compositingGroup().clipped()' lines as shown in the example code. There are two gray color shades, where I think the touch area is (roughly?) positioned. The same can be said if 'compositingGroup().clipped()' are active at position 1.1 and 2.1 (see comment). If 'compositingGroup().clipped()' get active at position 1.2 and 2.2 the gray bars get cut but the touch area is still wide and overlaps the left neighbor.

**See some screenshots:**

- [iPhone13portrait](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xhn2g.png)
- [iPhone13landscape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9LOt.png)

---

### **THE QUESTION:**

Is there a way of cutting or stretching the touch area for a Picker() object to fit its current stack?
Are there any ideas of using a number only keyboard with a return button?

---

### THE HARDWARE:

**Development Platforms:**

- MacBook Pro (Retina 13", Early 2015, Dual-Core Intel Core i5), FINE ON SIMULATORs AND PREVIEW (Canvas)(iPhone8, 13), Xcode 13.1
- MacBook Pro (16", 2021, Apple M1 Pro), Situation occurs on simulators and Preview (Canvas)(iPhone8, 13), Xcode: now 13.2.1

**Hardware Test Devices:**

- iPhone 6s, iOS Version: 15.2, Situation occurs
- iPhone X, iOS Version: 15.2, Situation occurs
- iPhone 13, iOS Version: 15.1.1, Situation occurs

### THE FULL EXAMPLE CODE (incl. Preview):

```
// demonstration file for bad multiple picker touch area overlay
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var rice: Int        = 51
    @State var corn: Int        = 20
    let range: ClosedRange<Int> = 0...99
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0){
                Spacer()
                VStack(){//picker 1
                    Text("rice")
                    VStack(){
                        Picker("", selection: $rice) {
                            ForEach(range, id: \.self){    Text("\($0)").tag($0)    }
                        }
                        //POSITION 1.1
                        .pickerStyle(.wheel)
                        //.compositingGroup()
                        //.clipped(antialiased: true)
                    }
                    //POSITION 1.2
                    .frame(width: 40, height: 100)
                    //.compositingGroup()
                    //.clipped(antialiased: true)
                    .border(Color.red)
                }
                Spacer()
                VStack(){//picker 2
                    Text("corn")
                    VStack(){
                        Picker("", selection: $corn) {
                            ForEach(range, id: \.self){    Text("\($0)").tag($0)    }
                        }
                        //POSITION 1.2
                        .pickerStyle(.wheel)
                        //.compositingGroup()
                        //.clipped(antialiased: true)
                    }
                    //POSITION 2.2
                    .frame(width: 40, height: 100)
                    //.compositingGroup()
                    //.clipped(antialiased: true)
                    .border(Color(UIColor.secondaryLabel))
                }
                Spacer()
            }// End of HStack
            .padding()
        }.overlay(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
                .stroke(lineWidth: 2)
        ).padding()
    }
}
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/62408309/12299030?

Comment: i have similar problem only in IOS15...buttons (and other controls) recognizes clicks only about 50px under the button itself. Like there was an invisible box under the button which can be clicked but not the button. It happens only with controls created in design mode and only after IOS 15 update. All of my controls works which was created from code. Now i re-write 3 apps to create everything from code and i wont use the designer anymore. :/

Comment: I just ran into this answering another [question about multi component pickers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70511898/7129318). The `.clipped()`, `.compositingGroup()` trick no longer work in iOS 15 to restrain the touch area. It has been filed as  FB9764631.

Comment: @Asperi: thank You for your advice. I tried the linked code and here is what I went with: // added 'var' to '@State var index = 0'
// added '.pickerStyle(.wheel)' to each picker since it in not the default
// added '.clipped()' to both Picker() --> little better in comparison to my example. I guess here is more place since I had a frame on my design.
// added third Picker() --> comparable bad situation as with my example

Comment: @Yrb: That's good to know. Would you be so kind to link us to the bug report source?

Comment: It is on the [Apple Developer Forum](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/687986).

Comment: Just found a solution to a similar problem in case you're still trying to solve this after 3 months haha https://stackoverflow.com/a/71637928/408286