# SwiftUI: scrolling on 3 wheel pickers inside a HStack is inaccurate

Tags: swiftui

I have 3 wheel pickers inside a HStack to allow for selecting hours, minutes, and seconds.

Here's the playground code to help illustrate the issue:

```
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

struct DurationPickers: View {
    @State private var hourSelection = 0
    @State private var minuteSelection = 0
    @State private var secondSelection = 0
    
    private let hoursArray = [Int](0..<24)
    private let minutesArray = [Int](0..<61)
    private let secondsArray = [Int](0..<61)
    
    private let fullHeight: CGFloat = 256
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                HStack(spacing: 0) {
                    Text("Hours")
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    Text("Minutes")
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    Text("Seconds")
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                HStack(spacing: 0) {
                    Picker(selection: self.$hourSelection, label: Text("")) {
                        ForEach(0 ..< self.hoursArray.count, id:\.self) { index in
                            Text("\( self.hoursArray[index])").tag(index)
                        }
                    }
                    .pickerStyle(WheelPickerStyle())
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width/3, alignment: .center)
                    
                    Picker(selection: self.$minuteSelection, label: Text("")) {
                        ForEach(0 ..< self.minutesArray.count, id:\.self) { index in
                            Text("\( self.minutesArray[index])").tag(index)
                        }
                    }
                    .pickerStyle(WheelPickerStyle())
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width/3, alignment: .center)
                    
                    Picker(selection: self.self.$secondSelection, label: Text("")) {
                        ForEach(0 ..< self.secondsArray.count, id:\.self) { index in
                            Text("\( self.secondsArray[index])").tag(index)
                        }
                    }
                    .pickerStyle(WheelPickerStyle())
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width/3, alignment: .center)
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            }
        }
        .frame(maxHeight: fullHeight)
        .background(Color.gray)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            DurationPickers()
        }
        .frame(width: 480, height: 600)
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ContentView())
```

The result of the code is this:

[image]

This looks exactly as I expect and want. However, when I try to select the hours for example, I have to scroll from the left half of the red area, otherwise minutes would start scrolling. The same happens if you scroll on minutes from the right half of the orange rectangle.

Any idea why it's behaving like this? Any suggestions to fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/65631488/12299030?

Comment: @Asperi Unfortunately it didn't fix the issue on Xcode 13.3 on both simulator and device

Answer (score 1):

In case someone else is having a similar issue, I just found a solution posted [on Apple's forums](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/687986) two weeks ago.

Previously, this behaviour was fixed by adding:

```
.compositingGroup().clipped()
```

As suggested in some of Asperi's answers. However, this solution have stopped working (probably since the release of iOS 15.1, but maybe later).

The solution that works now on iOS 15.4 is adding the following extension:

```
extension UIPickerView {
    open override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: UIView.noIntrinsicMetric, height: super.intrinsicContentSize.height)
    }
}
```

Not really sure what exactly is this doing and whether it might introduce other issues, but I'll go with it for now and keep testing!